# How to get cmd to search another dictionary

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

For example , if I need to use pip i'd have to navigate using cd like cd c:\Python34\Scripts then i'd be able to use pip , can't I just directly get to the scripts folder somehow .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to add the folder containing your scripts to the system PATH variable, and you should be good to go.

Comment: This worked for me , i'd be nice if you could add this http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm to your answer . or suggest a method yourself

Comment: @Vrisk [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](//superuser.com/q/284342)